# HDBC and multiple resultsets in a single statement: only first resultset returned

Tags: haskell, multiple-resultsets, hdbc

I'm looking for a way for [HDBC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC) to support multiple resultsets in a single statement

```haskell
testMultipleResultsetSingleStatement = do
  let sql = "select 1,2,3 union all select 2,3,4 select 'a', 'b'"
  c <- connectODBC connectionString
  rs <- quickQuery c sql []
  return rs
```

this will only return `[[SqlInt32 1,SqlInt32 2,SqlInt32 3],[SqlInt32 2,SqlInt32 3,SqlInt32 4]]`

We see here that the results from second resultset are discarded

I'm wondering if there is another function than quickQuery that would support this?

Ideally, the return type would be `[[[SqlValue]]]` instead of `[[SqlValue]]` so the first outermost list would correspond to each result set returned by the query.

If [HDBC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HDBC) doesn't provide a way for it, what other package would handle statements which returns multiple resultsets?

edit: Actually, a solution without API change would be to make it work this way:

```haskell
testMultipleResultsetSingleStatement = do
  let
    sql = "select 1,2,3 union all select 2,3,4 select 'a', 'b'"
  c <- connectODBC connectionString
  statement <- prepare c sql
  _ <- execute statement []
  rows1 <- fetchAllRows statement
  rows2 <- fetchAllRows statement
  return (rows1, rows2)
```

I checked and in the case of sqlserver it did return an empty list for rows2

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not supported currently in hdbc.

Though i see no purpose for this kind of feature.

How would it be better than

```
let sql1 = "select 1,2,3 union all select 2,3,4"
    sql2 = " select 'a', 'b'"

c <- connectODBC connectionString

rs1 <- quickQuery c sql1 []
rs2 <- quickQuery c sql2 []

return (rs1,rs2)
```

or if you really insist on having dirrerent records with different number of fileds and types of fields in one list (hmm weird but ok) you could do this:

```
return $ rs1 ++ rs2
```

Comment: the pros of single statement with multiple resultset is mostly in reducing the number of roundtrips to the database, I think it's common practice with networking related code. Not thinking about support in quickQuery, maybe the Statement record could contain a nextResults function returning a Bool, and subsequently issuing fetchRow would bring rows from the current resultset?